# Switch PRNG type in glibc

Tags: random, glibc

[Looking at glibc source](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=stdlib/random_r.c;h=a393dd3c199b5b08a16f3044f2a3bc21f8e88410;hb=HEAD) I see that it has five types of pseudo-random number generator implementations — TYPE's from 0 (being linear congruental) through 4. Besides, I can't find any clear examples of how to switch between ones. The default TYPE is 3, as documentation says. Would you please provide me with a simple example of how to switch to e.g. TYPE 4 PRNG?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You call [initstate](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/random.3.html) or [initstate_r](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/random_r.3.html) with an array of  8, 32, 64, 128, or 256 bytes which will correspond to initializing the PRNG to the TYPE 0 ... TYPE_4 algorithm.